# Scaling image by using width and height properties to fit in specified rectangle

Tags: html, image, image-scaling

Let's say I have a rectangle area (defined for example by a `div`) with some specified width and height. And I have an image with unpredictable size and aspect ratio.

If I'd like that image to fit withing given rectangle area and keep the original aspect ratio, how do I do it?

If I know in advance which side will be limiting I could specify only one dimension. For example if the rectangle have size 200x100 px and the image have size 400x300 px I could use `<img src="link/to/my/image.jpg" height="100px">` code and the image will keep its aspect ratio and will feet into my rectangle. But if the rectangle will be for example 100x100px the image will go out of the rectangle by the sides.

So the only thing I could do is to hind out the image size and do some simple calculations to define both width and height of the image to: keep the original ration and to fit in the specified rectangle for all possible combinations.

But it looks a bit complicated and requires to use graphic library on server side. May be I miss some HTML capabilities?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by putting this CSS code.

---

```
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

---

or the inverse

```
min-height: 100%; width: auto;
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

HTML

```
<div class='bounding-box'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bounding-box {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

OR -------------------------------

```
.bounding-box {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharath9207/t12qc8ab/)

Comment: I tried the first one. In my case worked `min-width: 100%; **max-width: 100%;** height: auto;` So I expect that is some cases (image smaller than the rectangle for example) I will get wrong result...

Comment: Well this all thing you can do and it is right answer and if by the way you want some gap like to make image smaller than you can use padding XX px according to your need it will give some gap from all the borders of your box and it will make your image fit.

Answer (score 0):

Easy,

```
<div id="rectangle" style="width:auto; height:auto;">
    <img src="link/to/my/image.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>
```

Or

```
<style>
#rectangle {width:auto; height:auto;}
</style>

<div id="rectangle">
    <img src="link/to/my/image.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>
```

Comment: As I understand if the image.jpg has the size of 200 by 100 pixels it will displayed stretched verically. Right? I'd like to keep the original aspect ratio.

Comment: Tried. I get what I expected: small square (smaller than the original box) with wrong aspect ratio.

Comment: could you post a picture

Comment: ok, first error i seen was after 'Alt' it should be 'alt="Title"'

Comment: honestly, I don't know how you could go about doing this... I'm stumped

Comment: Could you describe the things YOU are expected to be? May be you can make any screenshot as I made?

Comment: So which behavior did you expect?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is use photoshop or paint to adjust the width and height of the picture to fit the box, or you could just change the boxes size.

Comment: Can u get a pic of the CSS for the image and the rectangle

Comment: I'm not seeing any reason: the code `<img width="100px" height="100px" src="link/to/400by300px.png">` WILL result in the 100 by 100 picture with WRONG aspect ratio.

Comment: Try getting rid of width and height in the `img` area

Comment: @RomanMatveev Did getting rid of `width="" height=""` in the `img` tag work?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, if the rectangle is a fixed width and height, just make the max-width and max-height of the image element inside it be 100%.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PKG4d/

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px blue dotted;
}
.container > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/9088/855366.8a/0_a3175_3d12a514_orig.png"></div>
```

Comment: If the image will be smaller than the container I will get it smaller?

Comment: No, if the image is smaller than the container it will appear at its normal dimensions, not scaled.  It will only get scaled if it is larger than either the height or width of the container.